# Bounding $n \mapsto \int 1-e^{-n f(x)} dx$ when $f$ is merely integrable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a nonnegative integrable function on $\mathbb{R}_+ = [0,\infty)$.  I believe it is the case that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} 1-e^{-n f(x)} dx = o(n),$$
but I'm struggling to find a rigorous proof.  Of course, it's easily to establish the result for any particular $f(x) = x^{-p}$, $p>1$, but I'd like to make no assumption about $f$ other than those above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega(t) = m(\{ x : x \geq 0 \text{ and } f(x) > t \})$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-nf(x)}}{n}  \, dx
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{f(x)} e^{-nt} \, dtdx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-nt} \mathbf{1}_{\{f(x) > t\}} \, dtdx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-nt} \mathbf{1}_{\{f(x) > t\}} \, dxdt \tag{1}\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-nt}\omega(t) \, dt,
\end{align*}

where we have utilized the Tonelli's theorem in (1). Now the condition says that, by the same trick as above,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \omega(t) \, dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx < \infty, $$

which means that $\omega$ is integrable and dominates the sequence $(e^{-nt}\omega(t) : n \geq 1)$. Therefore by the dominated convergence theorem, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-nf(x)}}{n}  \, dx = o(1). $$

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference, or is this entirely your derivation?